# cmake run script for install target?

Tags: cmake

I have a project where "installing" the code is not quite as simple as just copying some files. With a traditional Makefile, I would just create a `make install` target that runs a series of shell commands to do what I need.

But googling around has resulting in no examples of this (some things close, but not quite... i think). So basically, I want a custom command, that depends on the target executables, but produces nothing and runs a script that need not be portable to accomplish the "install"

Anyone have any examples of something like this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

CMake's `install` command allows for custom scripts. See the official documentation: [`install` - Custom Installation Logic](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/install.html#custom-installation-logic):

> ```
> install([[SCRIPT <file>] [CODE <code>]]
>         [COMPONENT <component>] [...])
> ```
>
> The SCRIPT form will invoke the given CMake script files during installation. If the script file name is a relative path it will be interpreted with respect to the current source directory. The CODE form will invoke the given CMake code during installation. Code is specified as a single argument inside a double-quoted string. For example, the code
>
> ```
> install(CODE "MESSAGE(\"Sample install message.\")")
> ```
>
> will print a message during installation.

To run custom shell script (or whatever program), combine `install(CODE ...)` with [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/execute_process.html):

```
install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND my_script.sh)")
```

Comment: Sure, that'll let me run a cmake script. But can I do arbitrary bash commands during that?

Comment: @EvanTeran To do so you can use the `execute_process()` command like so: `INSTALL(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND pwd)")`. The quoting is going to be awful, so I strongly suggest that the command be a shell script. You can always pass the few parameters you need `... COMMAND my-script \"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}\" ...`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: use `add_custom_target`, then add the main target as a dependency to the custom target target.

```
# create custom target for setcap to be executed
add_custom_target(setcap ALL
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${OUTPUT_DIR}/bin
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E 'sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin+eip ${}/bin/<executable name>)
# create a dependency on the custom target for main target, setcap depends on ${proj_name}
add_dependencies(setcap ${proj_name})
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} setcat)` instead?

Comment: Please, edit your answer and swap them directly in your answer.

Comment: Wouldn't you want the project to build and install before you run the `setcap` command? In that case, it's correct as written, no? `add_dependencies(<target> <target_dependencies>)`.

Comment: In response to automaton’s question:  that could also be necessary, however to run and debug the code during development, setcap is run as the last step of the build, it is also run via a script as the last step of the install process.