# Have cmake run command on installed target binary

Tags: cmake

I'd like to run a command on a target after installing it.  I see "[cmake run script for install target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41254902/cmake-run-script-for-install-target)", which appears to be about running a single script after installing everything.  My question is a per-target script.

What I want to do is to run `patchelf` on an installed binary to change the interpreter.  This is much like how cmake will change the RPATH on the installed binary.  Looking into how this is done, I see stuff this in `cmake_install.cmake` (edited for brevity):

```
file(INSTALL DESTINATION "/bin" TYPE EXECUTABLE FILES "program")
file(RPATH_CHANGE
     FILE "$ENV{DESTDIR}/bin/program"
     OLD_RPATH "build-dir"
     NEW_RPATH "")
if(CMAKE_INSTALL_DO_STRIP)
    execute_process(COMMAND "/usr/bin/strip" "$ENV{DESTDIR}/bin/program")
endif()
```

This is changing the rpath and also stripping the binary after it is installed.  It seems like all I need to do is get one more `execute_process` put in there to run my patchelf command.  Yet I can't find any way to get cmake to do that.

It appears `add_custom_command(POST_BUILD ...)` is very close, but I do not want to modify the binary in the build directory, only after install, like how cmake modifies the rpath.