# CMake: How to setcap on target binary after install phase?

Tags: build, cmake

Is there some general way to run commands after the install phase for a target?
Issue here is that I need to set capabilities for executable, but if I use add_custom_command( TARGET ... ) signature it only applies to the binary in the build tree before it's copied to the bin folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cmake-run-script-for-install-target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41254902/cmake-run-script-for-install-target)

Comment: Did you check [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#targets)? You can provide a permissions argument to the `install()` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is to use CMake directive INSTALL( CODE ... ) as indicated by [cmake-run-script-for-install-target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41254902/cmake-run-script-for-install-target)