# Create deb package with autostart by CPack

Tags: bash, cmake, systemd, cpack

I am building a Debian package that should run as a service. Also, I have a file describing my service.

```
install(TARGETS "${SERVICE_NAME}"
        DESTINATION "bin"
        COMPONENT "${SERVICE_NAME}")

install(FILES "${SERVICE_NAME}.service"
        DESTINATION "/lib/systemd/system/"
        COMPONENT "${SERVICE_NAME}")

cpack_add_component_group("${SERVICE_NAME}")

cpack_add_component("${SERVICE_NAME}"
                    DISPLAY_NAME "${SERVICE_NAME}"
                    DESCRIPTION "${DESCRIPTION}"
                    GROUP "${SERVICE_NAME}"
                    INSTALL_TYPES Full)
```

I want to run after installing the package:

```
systemctl enable wb-rules && service wb-rules start
```

As another option, maybe CPack has a ready-made solution for installing systems.d services?

Comment: Why negative???

Comment: Not my downvote, but this is a broad question with no indication that you have researched the topic or actually tried anything. Perhaps you could [edit] your question to include a bit of background, including the code you have so far.

Comment: You can set a CPACK variable as this:
`set(CPACK_RPM_POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_FILE 
 ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/make/rpm/post")`  
And inside the post script run anything you want.

Comment: Consider creating a `postinst` (bash) script (possibly with cmake `file(WRITE ...)` then tell CpackDEB to include these files via `CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA`. Don't forget a `prerm` script to stop and remove the service. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/deb.html#variable:CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`add_custom_command()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events) with the `POST_BUILD` parameter. Something like :

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${MY_TARGET} POST_BUILD COMMAND service my-service start)
```

Comment: No, these are solutions for the build process.
I need to run the script after installation.

Comment: Ok so you can do `install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND systemctl enable wb-rules && service wb-rules start)")` find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41254902/cmake-run-script-for-install-target)

Comment: This solution also executes the script during the creation of the deb package. 
I'm looking for a solution that will allow the script to run during the installation of Debian package on the user's computer.
Script should be executed after "apt-get install my_package.deb"

Comment: I don't think it concerns cmake.